# Ошибка в коде, при работе с admin-панелью

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Пытаюсь перейти к админ-панели, вот код файла:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url, include
 from django.contrib import admin

 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^', include('MemesSite.urls')),
     url(r'^news/$', include('news.urls'))
    ]
```

Но я ловлю ошибку

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py in has_permission, line 162
```

Что делать? С чем связана ошибка?

Вот список MIDdLEWEARE:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

(ВЕРСИЯ DJANGO 1.8)

Comment: Добавьте в свой пост список MIDDLEWARE из settings.py и версию джанги, пожалуйста.

Comment: @floydya добавил

Comment: Попробуйте сменить имя с MIDDLEWARE на MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Comment: Ну так как, помогло? Смена этих имён возвращает старый стиль отображения

Comment: @FedotSoldier NoReverseMatch at /admin/
Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/$logout/$']

Comment: Переименуйте MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES обратно в MIDDLEWARE и удалите оттуда 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'              Убедитесь, что в INSTALLED_APPS есть 'django.contrib.auth' и 'django.contrib.contenttypes'  И добавьте 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' в MIDDLEWARE                   Если все так и есть - пишите

Comment: Если предыдущий способ не сработал попробуйте переименовать MIDDLEWARE обратно на MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. Добавьте туда 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware' Если не сработает удалите 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' и попробуйте еще раз